# Nitinol FEA using Advanced Simulation NX

Tags: finite-element-method

Is there a tutorial on how to do non-linear FEA using Siemens Advanced Simulation NX (not remap) with Nitinol, preferably using sol 601. An example would be very helpful, I searched online but most just have Ansys or abacus examples.